# Credibility interval for Model, M(A,B)

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, model, quantiles, credible-interval

Supposing you've a model M(A,B) dependent on parameters A and B. You've successfully generated 10,000 samples from the posterior distributions for A and for B. The 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of the posterior distributions for A and B act as estimates for a 95% credibility interval for A and B. If one wanted to obtain a credibility interval for M(A,B) would one plug in the posterior distributions of A and B into the model, essentially simulating the model 10,000 times, then look at the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of the output for M(A,B)?

If not, how would one calculated an interval for M(A,B)? You have residual values calculated between the model and data, and you've made the assumption the error term, e, will be normally distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation sigma. Essentially Data = M(A,B) + e. How would one calculate an interval for such model?

Comment: How do you get your posterior samples of A and B? As they are "posterior", I would think the data model you give at the end would enter their calculation?

Comment: I used the an algorithm called the metropolis hasting algorithm. It assumes the errors between the model and data are normally distributed. What do you mean by enter their calculation?

Comment: I was just thinking that if the errors have a broader/narrower distribution, this would likely make the posteriors for A and B themselves broader/narrower.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm thinking, but I;m unsure how to implement this given the posterior distrinutions